# Using Pusher with SimpleWebRTC

Tags: javascript, pusher, simplewebrtc

I've come across the SimpleWebRTC package. Trying to get it to work, but can't seem to get the remote stream coming through. I'm also using Pusher for signalling, rather than the default that comes with SimpleWebRTC.

I've set up my own connection:

```
var myConnection = {
  pusher: new Pusher('mypusherkey', { cluster: 'ap1' } ),
  channel: null, 

    on: function (event, callback) { 
        this.pusher.bind (event, callback); 
    },
    emit: function () { 
        if (arguments.length == 1) {
            if (arguments[0] === "join") {
                this.channel = this.pusher.subscribe(arguments[1]);
            } 
        }
        else 
            this.channel.trigger(arguments); 
    },
    getSessionId: function() { 
        return this.pusher.connection.socket_id;  
    },
    disconnect: function() { 
        this.pusher.disconnect(); 
    }
};
```

Then I have the SimpleWebRTC initialisation:

```
var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
  // the id/element dom element that will hold "our" video
  localVideoEl: 'localVideo',
  // the id/element dom element that will hold remote videos
  remoteVideosEl: 'remotesVideos',
  // immediately ask for camera access
  autoRequestMedia: true,
  debug: true,
  connection: myConnection
});

// we have to wait until it's ready
webrtc.on('readyToCall', function () {
    console.log('ready to join');
  // you can name it anything
  webrtc.joinRoom('test-video-chat');
});
```

Doing a simple test between 2 PCs, it's not setting up the remote stream. In the dev console apart from the intitial event hook ups, I'm not seeing any other activity happening, especially SimpleWebRTC "readyToCall" not firing.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to emit a 'connect' signal from your socket adapter to trigger [this code](https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC/blob/master/simplewebrtc.js#L74-L78)

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where should I be triggering the connect?

Comment: Also is my Pusher connection right? Or is there something I've missed?

Comment: In a post in the github repository, a person has helped, and they pointed out I'd need to listen to a few events. I've kinda tried that but I still can't get it to work. I'm now just confused about what events I should be listening to and how I should be processing them.